# error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such type

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

My Type Converter

```
import androidx.room.TypeConverter
import com.amin.movie.vo.Query

object QueryTypeConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun queryToString(query: Query?): String? = if (query != null) Query.toJson(query) else null

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun stringToQuery(data: String?): Query? = if (data != null) stringToQuery(data) else null
}
```

and Entity is

```
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import androidx.room.TypeConverters
import com.amin.movie.db.MovieTypeConverters
import com.amin.movie.db.QueryTypeConverter
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

@Entity
@TypeConverters(QueryTypeConverter::class)
data class MovieSearchResult(
        // and other fields
        @PrimaryKey
        val query: Query
)
```

that error happend when i want make my project
error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.

Comment: did you find the solution to this problem?

Comment: I had the same problem. I found it my Dao interface. I have a logical problem in the Dao interface.you should check your Dao file.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code on the [latest release of Room at this time](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.1.0-rc01) and it works for me. I've created a [Database](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Database) and a [Dao](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Dao) to make sure it works and everything seems fine.
Even though your method now works, this isn't the one they show in the kotlin examples in the [Room documentation for kotlin](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#kotlin). 
[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data)'s their example on [TypeConverter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/TypeConverter) and this is how it would apply to your specific case (I've also provided the [Database](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Database) and [Dao](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Dao) I've made):

```
// The query class wasn't provided so this is just a simple
// class with a toJson static method
data class Query(var query: String) {
    companion object {
        fun toJson(query: Query): String {
            return query.query
        }
    }
}

@Entity
@TypeConverters(QueryTypeConverter::class)
data class MovieSearchResult(
    // and other fields
    @PrimaryKey
    val query: Query
)

class QueryTypeConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun queryToString(query: Query?): String? = if (query != null) Query.toJson(query) else null

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToQuery(data: String?): Query? = if (data != null) stringToQuery(data) else null
}

@Dao
interface MovieSearchResultDao {
    @Insert
    fun insert(r: MovieSearchResult)

    @Update
    fun update(r: MovieSearchResult)

    @Delete
    fun delete(r: MovieSearchResult)
}

@Database(entities=arrayOf(MovieSearchResult::class), version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun dao(): MovieSearchResultDao
    companion object {
        private var DB: AppDatabase? = null;
        public fun instance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            var db = DB
            if (db == null) {
                db = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    AppDatabase::class.java, "database-name"
                ).build()
                DB = db
            }
            return db
        }
    }
}
```